# asp labels - text change

Tags: asp-classic

```
<label id="ButtonTestResultLabel" style="color:Black; font-size:large"  title="Success" visible=true>Please Press Left Button</label> 
    <% if scanner.ExecuteButtonTest(sessionid, CInt(1)) then
        upbuttonresult = true
    end if %>
    <% ButtonTestResultLabel.Text = "Please Press Down Button"
    if scanner.ExecuteButtonTest(sessionid, CInt(2)) then
        downbuttonresult = true
    end if %>
```

I want to change the label text but I'm getting error:

> Parse error in script
>   Microsoft VBScript runtime error: '800a01a8'
>   Description: Object required: 'ButtonTestResultLabel'
>
> In file: /prod/buttonstest.asp
>   On line: 57

How can I change the label text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing ASP static content with ASP.NET runat="Server" controls.  There is no such object with an ID of `ButtonTestResultLabel` in your ASP script.  Your goal is achieved like follow although note that your fragment of code doesn't make a lot of sense so I've kinda made up some logic to demonstrate.

```
<%

    Function ButtonState()
        For i = 1 to 4
            If scanner.ExecuteButtonTest(sessionid, CInt(i)) then
                ButtonState = i
                Exit For 
            End If
        Next
    End Function

    Function ButtonTestResultLabelText()

         Select Case ButtonState
           Case 1
               ButtonTestResultLabelText = "Please Press Down Button" 
           Case 2
               ButtonTestResultLabelText = "Please Press Up Button"
           Case 3
               ButtonTestResultLabelText = "Please Press Right Button" 
           Case Else
               ButtonTestResultLabelText = "Please Press Left Button"
        End Select
    End Function


 %>


<label id="ButtonTestResultLabel" style="color:Black; font-size:large"  title="Success" visible=true><%=ButtonTestResultLabelText%></label>
```

The key here is the embedding of the `<%=...%>` syntax in the html where you want dynamic content to appear.